# How to copy folder to shared-directory in VBS?

Tags: windows, vbscript, shared-directory

I'm using `FileSystemObject.CopyFolder` method to do this, but I have no idea with accessing shared folder. Is there any methods in VBScript to deal with authentication of shared directory?

Comment: Did you try mapping a network drive (i.e. S:\\sharefolder where S is the mapped drive) or using the computer name of the shared directory in the CopyFolder method? (i.e. \\computername\sharefolder). As for authentication, the user which VBS is running under will need access to the shared directory, OR you will have to impersonate a valid user in code (which i am not sure if it is possible in VBS)

Comment: Indeed mapping the share to a network drive is the way to go when authentication is involved.